# display specific value in JSON object by ARRAY value

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuejs2

**I have a JSON array and another array as follows.**

> JSON OBJECT

```
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'abc',
      email: 'abc@gmail.com',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'def',
      email: 'def@gmail.com',
    },
```

> SELECTED ARRAY

```
['id', 'email']
```

> QUESTION

the selected array can have any key value of JSON Object what I want is JSON array should show the specific keys that are selected by a selected array

> WHAT I TRIED

```
  let jsonData = {};
  let arr = [];

  this.selectedExcelTitle.forEach((element) => {
    var columnName = element;
    jsonData[columnName] = this.Users.forEach((e) => {
      return e.element;
    });
  });
  arr.push(jsonData);
```

Comment: Do you want to filter the "JSON OBJECT" bases on "SELECTED ARRAY"?

Comment: yes, based on the question @AnandG.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This snippet filters each entry of the given `jsonObject` (array of objects) so that the resulting `filteredJsonObject`(array) only contains key-value pairs with a key that is contained in your `selectedArray`.

```js
var filteredJsonObject = jsonObject.map(function(entry) {
    return selectedArray.reduce(function(res, key) {
        res[key] = entry[key];
        return res;
    }, {});
});
```